# JQuery external file not working

Tags: jquery, file, external

I have a jQuery file called login.js:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var login = function () {
    $("a#register").click(function () {
        $("form#login").hide();
        $("form#signup").show();
    });
    $("a#login").click(function () {
        $("form#login").show();
        $("form#signup").hide();
    });
}
</script>
```

with the following HTML:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  login();
});
</script>
```

and got this in the header:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/login.js"></script>
```

The jQuery code isn't working like this, while it works if I include it directly in the HTML, any thoughts on why it isn't working?

Comment: take out the `<script>` tags from the .js file

Comment: Sounds like it might be a path issue. Try an absolute path?

Comment: That seems to be working yes, thank you! Any ideas on how to use a relative path though?

Comment: Depends on what the folder hierarchy is.

Comment: the index.html is in an folder and in that same folder is another folder called scripts, that one contains the jquery file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/login.js"></script>
```

Login.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#register").click(function() {
        $("form#login").hide();
        $("form#signup").show();    
    });

    $( "a#login" ).click(function() {
        $("form#login").show();
        $("form#signup").hide();    
    });
});
```

Possible fixes:

1. `<script>` tags in JS file
2. Changed from `../scripts/` to `scripts/`

Answer (score 0):

Try moving login.js to the same location as the page you are calling it (let's say, *web/index.php* and *web/login.js*). If that works, then the problem you have is with the location of the JS file you are pointing from your header.

I recommend you always use simple routes to CSS and JS files (like /css and /js), to avoid using ".../path/to/file.js. That way, your code should be this simple:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/login.js"></script>
```

You can improve it, if it suits you, using PHP variables to point to the server home location and thus making the path absolute, like in this example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $_SERVER['HOME']; ?>/script/login.js"></script>
```

I hope this helps.